# A type of reshaping operation

Tags: r

Say I have

```
dta <- data.frame(
  id_1=as.integer(runif(1000,0,20) * 20),
  id_2=as.integer(runif(1000,0,5) * 5),
  X=LETTERS[as.integer(cut(runif(5),0:3/3))]
  )
```

I would like to replace X with three columns, A, B, C. The value of these columns will be TRUE if X with the value corresponding to the new table name was observed in dta for that particular combination of id_1 and id_2, and FALSE otherwise. As a very simple example:

```
id_1 = {1, 1, 3}
id_2 = {1, 1, 2}
X  = {A, B, A}
```

Would become:

```
id_1 = {1, 3}
id_2 = {1, 2}
A = {TRUE, TRUE}
B = {TRUE, FALSE}
C = {FALSE, FALSE}
```

I think this is a type of reshaping operation, but cannot think how to do it using the usual functions.

## Update

I thought the following worked:
Using dplyr:

```
dta  %>% 
distinct  %>% 
mutate(y=1)  %>% 
spread(X, y, fill=FALSE)
```

However the sum of each row is only '1', and so some additional merging is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R solution:

```
aggregate(X~id_1+id_2,dta,table)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(dta, id_1+id_2~X, value.var='X', 
      fun.aggregate= function(x) as.logical(length(x)))
```